# Compositions $(n_1,...,n_r)$ of an integer $m$ such that $i$ divides $n_i$

Tags: co.combinatorics, partitions

I am studying the compositions $(n_1,...,n_r)$ of an integer $m$ such that $i\vert n_i$ for all $i=1,...,r$. (Recall that a composition $(n_1,...,n_r)\vDash m$ of $m$ is just a sequence $(n_1,...,n_r)\in \mathbb{P}^r$ of positive integers for which $n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_r=m$.) Here the length $r$ of the composition is not fixed.

Is anything known about these compositions? More specifically, can we relate the number of these compositions to the number of partitions of $m$? Does it have asymptotic expansions that approximate it or recurrence relations that calculate it exactly?

If for whatever reasons it helps, it can be assumed that $m=24$.

Comment: Are you assuming that $n_1\geq n_2\geq\cdots\geq n_r$?

Comment: No, I am not. Also, $r$ is not fixed. I have edited my post so no confusion can arise.

Comment: Do you require that the numbers are positive, or merely non-negative? If positive, it should be called integer compositions, and if non-negative, it is usually called weak compositions.

Comment: Thanks. I require them to be positive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number $f(m)$ of such sequences is the number $q(m)$ of partitions of $m$ into distinct parts (https://oeis.org/A000009). For a bijection, take your sequence $(n_1,\dots,n_r)$ and let $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_r)$ be the conjugate partition (using the standard definition of partition) of the partition with $(n_i-i)/i$ $i$'s.  Then $(\lambda_1+r,\lambda_2+r-1,\dots,\lambda_r+1)$ is a partition of $m$ into distinct parts, and conversely.

An asymptotic formula appears for instance in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2303741.

Answer (score 6):

For a fixed $r$, these are in an one-to-one correspondence with conventional partitions of $m$ into parts $\leq r$ where each part $i$ is present at least once (just set $n_i$ equal the sum of all parts $i$). This further corresponds to the partitions of $m-\tfrac{r(r-1)}2$ with the largest part being $r$, [given by $p_r(m-\tfrac{r(r-1)}2)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts).